# the unit of grid (floor grid) is different for differnet object

Tags: modeling

Hi veryone Im very new here in blender.

I just confused by the unit of the floor grid. I have a gallery model which is about 50m * 50m size, but the location of the ground is something abnormal

[image]

the locationX of the ground(plane) is -8825.3m, it is far away from the zero, but the scene shows that the center of ground is just 2 unit away from (0,0,0), so I think it should be -2m, not -8825.3m, then I try to move the ground about 1 unit of grid towards the X axis and it shows that is 1000m very unit.

I dont understand that and add a cube to the ground, then I move one unit towards the x
axis again, and it is 1meter. This result is what I think is right.

[image]

so is there anyone can explain me with this, thanks a lot!

I have uploaded the blender file:
[image]

Comment: Your Plane is probably parented to another object, that is far from centre and its Scale is not 1 ... to help more you should give us more info or share simplified file (just with the plane if issue still persist). Use https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: @vklidu hey vklidu~ I have uploaded file.  And yes ,it is parented to another object, but I check the parent postion which is 0,0,0  and with some roation. I still cannot figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing here is that ...

When you parent object to another you create a relation ship *Child > Parent*, where *Parent* object location became an origin (0,0,0) of *Child* object ... the Child's location is displayed as **local space**.

It means - when Parent's location is set what ever, Child's location will be measured as Parent is at zero location.
(In your case if you move the Circle to the Ground (Empty) location, than Circle will be at 0,0,0 location in its local space (not world space).

Similar thing happens with "weird" distances ... the "Sketchfab_model" (Empty object) that is at the highest position of hierarchy, **was scaled down to 0.001** after Children was parented ... so Children real scale and location dimension is 1*1000.

The best to understand is to play with parenting ... open a new scene with *Cube* add *Empty* (or what ever), parent *Cube* to *Empty* and try to change locations and scales both individually to see what Loc, Rot Scale became ...

Comment: I got it,  because the parent scale 0.001, that's why child behavior strange。Thank you very much!